# how to reference a cell on a loaded table through power query editor even if the number of rows change?

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I used power query editor to reference a folder that has many different excel files in it. Using PQE, im reading hte most recent file and doing basic ETL with it and loading it back to the workbook.

Within the loaded table via PQE, I want to reference specfic cells to another sheet.

However, when there's a new excel workbook loaded into that folder and power query reads the new excel file and loads it to the worbook, the referenced cell could no longer be there anymore.

i.e.

[image]

in this example right here, we have 4 rows that are spit out.
[image]

in the 2nd refresh, 3 rows are spit out.

In the first picture I want to reference D4 to another worksheet.
But after refreshing with PQE as seen in the 2nd image, D4 is no longer available and the sheet that i originally referenced D4 to is sayingh #REF!.

even if the number of rows change, how can i continue having the sheet still referencing D4 even if its not there from the loaded table through PQE.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to have the result of a powerquery just be cell D4 in the source information? If so, do below  (If you are looking to reference a cell that does not exist in a table already loaded from powerquery, reference that table and wrap it in an =iferror()  )

To return just cell D4 in PowerQuery from a table, use this syntax

D4 = try Table.Column(Source,Table.ColumnNames(Source){3}){3} otherwise null

and paste that into home ... advanced editor...

The first {3} is the column starting from 0, the 2nd {3} is the row starting from zero

The null is the value when the table does not contain cell D4. You could change it to be a zero or something else

Full sample code:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
D4 = try Table.Column(Source,Table.ColumnNames(Source){3}){3} otherwise null
in D4
```